# Deleting redundant records from a table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete everything in accounts that don't have any contacts....
So why is this statement wrong, and how can I fix it?
(String `sGUID` is the foreign key field; don't ask - it's not my schema)

```
delete from accounts as X
where X.ID in (
    select A.ID as ID 
    from   accounts as A
    left join
           contacts as C
    on     A.sGUID = C.sGUID 
    where  C.ID is null 
)
```

The `select` clause on it's own is fine, and returns the IDs I'd expect.

The full query above tells me I have an error in my SQL syntax.... 
If I replace `as X where X.ID in` with a simple `where ID in`  I am told that I

> can't specify target table accounts for update in from clause.

This strikes me as a pretty simple operation - there must be something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` in `delete` itself:

```
delete A
from accounts as A
left join contacts as C on A.sGUID = C.sGUID
where C.ID is null;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was simple! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following does what you want:

```
delete a from accounts a
     where not exists (select 1
                       from contacts c
                       where a.sGUID = c.sGUID
                      );
```